# How to set custom field in import Excel into Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have created an property as `Square`.

When I import Excel file into Prestashop I can not select this field  from select list.

How to add this field?

Comment: What do you call "property"? Do you meant "attribute"?

Comment: Yes, attribute or it is named as features of product

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **products** and **combinations** separately.

Go to `Advanced Parameters > Import` and download the sample file.

[image]